# Search results that include words in the category and tags? WP

Tags: wordpress, search

EDIT: Solved my main question.

I'm going around in circles here, finding similar questions but nothing quite right.

Q: I'm trying to add search results that include words in the category and tags.

For example; I have posts with *documentary* in the title and or description but not the title of the said documentary. If I search for the name of this documentary that isn't mentioned in the title and or description but it's filed under category x and or tags then I'd like it to show up in search. Reason being, I made posts about the documentary before I knew the name of it yet.

Also, is there a way to divide search results up, such as:

News (Posts) results found:
Page results found:
Or somewhere in the title that says what type of result each one is (post or page)

If too complicated, don't worry about that one. I'm mainly focusing on the main question.

I'm ever so grateful for your help. Thank you in advance.

My search.php is this:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?> 

<?php get_sidebar(); ?> 

<div id="content">

<div class="article">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php
                global $wp_query;
                $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
                ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Search results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
                <br/><br/>
                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="date">
          <?php the_time('M j, Y') ?>        </div><div class="posttitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>

                <?php endwhile; ?> 

</div>



<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } 

else { ?>

<div class="right"><?php next_posts_link('Next Page &raquo;') ?></div>

<div class="left"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Page') ?></div>

<?php } ?>


<br><br><br>


<?php else : ?>



<div class="posttitle">Nothing found. Try something else?</div>

This page doesn't exist



<?php endif; ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What was the solution?